# How do I display a digital timer (StopWatch) in datagridview column dynamically c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, timer, stopwatch

I have datagridview whose datasource is datatable.

I have two columns in datagridview:

NAME, IN TIME

After the datagridview is loaded, I want to add a new column called DURATION which is a timer column i.e. based on the IN TIME, DURATION column should display a stopwatch with the timespan interval of CURRENT TIME-IN TIME.

How do I make the DURATION column stopwatch to continue the timer for every seconds like digital clock?

Comment: How many rows did you have in your grid ?

Comment: @Steve For every thirty seconds, datagridview is updated. Row will not exceed more than twenty

Comment: Does it need to be decorated digital clock or a string `hh:mm;ss` that change every second should be ok?

Comment: @Sakura Ya. thats what I need  hh:mm:ss

Comment: That can be done use `Timer` and `delegate` event. Could you post your code about C# data struct and how you bind it to DGV?

Comment: Its simple. I just fill the datatable using dataadapter and setting the datagridview1.datasource=datatable;

Comment: I know it can be done using timer for single row. For multiple rows, should I create multiple timer? That would be bad performance right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a string column to `DataTable` and use it as duration column. Then you can subscribe to `Tick` event of a timer which you set it's interval to 1000 and show the result of count down timer in duration column:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach( DataRow row in YourDataTable.Rows)
    {
        var diff = row.Field<DateTime>("DateTimeColumn").Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        if(diff.TotalSeconds>0)
        {
            row["DurationColumn"] = string.Format("{0} d {1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}", 
                                       diff.Days, diff.Hours, diff.Minutes, diff.Seconds);
        }
        else
        {
            row["DurationColumn"] = "0 d 00:00:00";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to display the duration changes in datagridview.

Comment: Above code performs what you need. It shows a count down timer in the cells of duration column that shows duration between specified time and now. The timer, updates cells each second.

Comment: I just have a doubt. After assigning a datagridview.datasource=datatable; If I make any changes in datatable, will it be reflected in datagridview immediately

Comment: When you change a value in `DataTable`, changes will be reflected to `DataGridView` immediately. `DataTable` supports two way data binding.

Comment: Since the IN TIME is always lesser than CURRENT TIME.                 var inTime = row.Field<DateTime>("IN TIME");
                var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
                var diff = currentTime - inTime;

Comment: I made this small change. It works perfectly. Thanks @Reze Aghaei