# Update a specific cell in a ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView on another form that I populate with this code

```
if (choice <= 1)
            {

                ListViewItem items = new ListViewItem(new[]
                {
                    activity, statusType, blueprintName, runs, installerName, actTime, endDate, location
                });
                lstvw.Items.Add(items);
            }
```

I change the data on the ListView with several different outputs using this code or similar for the other outputs.

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Visible = false;
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        rbInt = 1;
        choice = rbInt + cbInt;
        listviewcolumnbuilder();
        worker.IndustryReturns(choice, listView1);
        this.Text = "Industry Jobs - All Jobs";
        listView1.Visible = true;
    }
```

I want to update a specific cell, in this case actTime, that is a DateTime that I convert to a string.  That value specifically counts down to 0 on certain date.

What would be a good way to update just that specific cell automatically?

Comment: Find the sub item and change its text. What kind of automatic way do you expect?

Comment: I was thinking with a timer.  The data is static and I want it to count down.

Comment: You can simply use `Tick` event of the timer and find the sub items you need to update and update its text. Here is an example using `DataGridView` and `DataTable`. [How do I display a digital timer (StopWatch) in datagridview column dynamically c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668173/how-do-i-display-a-digital-timer-stopwatch-in-datagridview-column-dynamically/35669823#35669823)