# Trying to apply a "digital clock" to each row in a "Timer" column using Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a form using `dataGridView` and `CellFormatting`. One of the columns in my `dataGridView` is a "Timer" which should basically show how long that row has been in my `dataGridView`.

What I have so far (referencing [How do I display a digital timer (StopWatch) in datagridview column dynamically c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668173/how-do-i-display-a-digital-timer-stopwatch-in-datagridview-column-dynamically))

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FillData();
        dataGridView.CellFormatting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.cell_formatting);
        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView);
        start_timer();    

    }

    void start_timer()
    {
       System.Windows.Forms.Timer clock = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        clock.Interval = 1000;
        clock.Tick += new EventHandler(clock_tick);
        clock.Enabled = true;           
    }

    void clock_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
           //????
        }
    }
```

The difference between the aforementioned thread and my situation is I'm using `DataGridView` whereas... I'm not sure what the other user was using. I don't seem to have access to "DataRow" like he does. When I try to use `DataRow` in my foreach loop, I get:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.
```

I could try checking each row for a certain value that I manually insert as a flag, then set that `row[column] = DateTime.Now` (with some math to determine length that it's been in there..)

Any advice would be appreciated!

@Reza Aghaei fixed it. Simply updating each object in my datasource then `datasource.ResetBindings()` each tick.

Thanks!

Comment: The other answer is using `DataTable` and updates 'DurationColumn' column of `DataRow` in `Tick` event of the timer. You can update the property of your data model class.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. What is my "data model class"?

Comment: For example if you have a `Record` class, containing `ElapsedTime` property, you can change it.

Comment: Oh.... Wow, I think I get it. One sec.

Comment: `foreach(Record record in RecordList){ ...}`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, and it's kind of working. Problem is now my Cells aren't updating every second, I have to "click" on them to get them to update. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the type of `DataSource`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123475/discussion-between-mrdysprosium-and-reza-aghaei).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Reza Aghaei has the answer:

```
        void clock_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tick");
        foreach(Record record in record_list)
        {
            record.EvtTimeString = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
        record_list.ResetBindings();
    }
```